# How can I assign an output(tuple) into a key value? Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

I have this output

```
(10.76, 27.73)
```

and I want to assign it to a key as a value, here is a code

```
dictionary = {'whatever':'whatever, 'KEY':'I need this output(tuple) here'}
```

Also, little detail, I would prefer to keep the comma, but if not possible i'll just add it on my own, that's ok.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign it.

```
>>> t = (10.76, 27.73)
>>> d = {}
>>> d['key'] = t
>>> d
{'key': (10.76, 27.73)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mytuple = (10.76, 27.73)
dictionary = {'whatever':'whatever', 'KEY':mytuple}`

{'KEY': (10.76, 27.73), 'whatever': 'whatever'}

or

`mytuple = (10.76, 27.73)
dictionary = {'whatever':'whatever', 'KEY':str(mytuple)}`

{'KEY': '(10.76, 27.73)', 'whatever': 'whatever'}